# how to change default theme color in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

How can the default theme color be changed in Magento 1.9 i want to change #Theme Color 1 And #Theme color 2 but i can't find how?

My admin configuration is :

[image]

Comment: do you use any theme or default magento

Comment: i will use theme

Comment: if you use theme there will be option for changing color in admin panel

Comment: yes i will shown and i will try to change but can't work it

Comment: can you send admin screenshot where you are changing  and frontend link so that it will be easy to debug

Comment: yes i will   go to this link i wiil attach my screen shot http://imgur.com/a/DEb97

Comment: so you applied #cca972 color

Comment: yes its themes default color i want change but can't

Comment: did you clear magento cache after color changed and in frontend ctrl+F5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you provided your problem is the CSS is commented out.

If you remove `/*` at the start and `*/` at the end, then clear all caches I suspect it will work.

[image]